# Removing a redundant element from a cycle in an ERD

Tags: database-design, relationship, erd

I hope its ok to ask on here.. its from Coursera  and I am not sure I agree with the suggested solution for this exercise.
I have to improve an ERD for a car dealership.

here is a brief description.

The cars incur some expenses before they are sold to customers. The employee who completes the sales transaction, also processes the payment. Each payment should be associated with 1 account.
There are the minimum cardinalities of 0 of Sold, MakesSale and Purchases for Vehicle (0,1) because a car can remain on the lot some days before it is sold.

That's my amended diagram.
[image]

I would remove the Sold relationship from here.

However, the suggested solution says that Process is redundant because the same employee completes the sale and processes the payment.

Can either of them be removed? If not, can somebody please explain why removing Processes is a better idea.

Thank you.

A more detailed description of the problem is below.

Mountain High Quality Vehicles dealership would like to develop an inventory management database to improve its tracking of vehicles, sales, and expenses.  The dealership also would like to track information about its customers and car(s) sold to its customers.

•   Vehicle Acquisitions:  Periodically the owners attend auctions and purchase pre owned cars seeking reasonable prices and quality vehicles.  They also purchase pre-owned vehicles from the wholesale market. The purchased vehicles are transported to the dealership and inspected for mechanical problems. Each vehicle is fixed and cleaned before being placed for sale.

•   Vehicle Improvements:  Apart from purchases, the dealership has additional expenses to prepare vehicles for market.  The expenses typically involve transporting the purchased vehicle to the dealership, checking the vehicle for any potential problem, repairs and maintenance if necessary, marketing and cleaning.

•   Sales Details:  Customers purchase vehicles at the dealership. Each sale involves one customer even for married couples. Although customers can purchase more than one vehicle, each vehicle is recorded as a separate sale. When a sale is completed, the employee associated with the sale and payments are recorded. Typically, vehicles remain on the lot for a period of time before sales occur.

•   Vehicle Details: The database tracks the unique vehicle identifier and vehicle identification number (VIN) to complete a sales transaction.  The database also tracks vehicle characteristics such as make, model, year, mileage, exterior and interior colors, transmission type (automatic or manual), and number of cylinders (4 or 6).

•   Customer Details: The database records the unique customer number, first and last names, address, city, state, postal code, primary phone number, and cellphone number.

•   Expense Details: Each vehicle expense has a unique expense identifier, expense type, expense description, expense amount, expense paid date, account, and associated vehicle.

•   Account Details: The database tracks account details such as a unique account identifier, account description, related expenses, and related payments.

•   Payment Details: The database also tracks the vehicle sale (payment process).  Each payment has a unique invoice number and payment method.  The payment options are cash, credit card, or external line of credit as no financing is available at the dealership. Typically one payment is made per sale although multiple payments are sometimes made if a customer provides cash for part of the sale. If a customer is paying with a credit card, the payment includes the credit card number, expiration date, name on the credit card, and payment description. The employee that completed the sales transaction and vehicle should be recorded. The same employee works as sales associate and processes the payment to complete the sale. Each payment is associated with one account for company accounting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the suggested solution says that Process is redundant because
> the same employee completes the sale and processes the payment.

Yes, since there is no business value added when having the EmployeeID in the Payment table and the Vehicle table.
If the process can be completed by a different employee comparing to the one who sold the car, than it is mandatory to have the EmployeeID in both Payment and Vehicle tables.

> The purchased vehicles are transported to the dealership and inspected
> for mechanical problems. Each vehicle is fixed and cleaned before
> being placed for sale.

You may need a table for the `Dealership` and a table for `Mechanical Report`.
The `Mechanical Report` table should include the DealershipID and the `VehicleID`.

> Customers purchase vehicles at the dealership.

You may need a table `Purchases` which gathers the `VehicleID`, the `DealershipID`, the `CustomerID` instead of having a direct relationship between the Vehicle and Customer.

Comment: thank you for an interesting insight. there is only one dealership, Mountain High Quality Vehicles.

Comment: @bluetail even if there is only one dealership, you need to mention that in your design